# How to prove an interval $[0, 1]$ is not a null set?!

Tags: measure-theory, almost-everywhere

I am studying Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability.
By the way, an example of this criterion says that the Dirichlet function is not integrable because " $[0, 1]$ is not a null set ".

How can I show that $[0, 1]$ is not a null set?

I tried to find explanations about this but all of them were related to measure theory, which I don't study. (I am just reading the introduction to real analysis by Bartle)
Are there any proofs without measure theory?

Comment: What is your definition of null set?  The most common definition uses measure theory, so unless you say what different definition you're using you can't hope to prove it without some measure theory...

Comment: In measure theory a set $A$ is a **null set** with respect to measure $\mu$ if a measurable set $B$ exists such that $A\subseteq B$ and $\mu(B)=0$. With respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\mathbb R$ the set $[0,1]$ is not a null set because $[0,1]\subseteq B$ implies that $\lambda(B)\geq\lambda([0,1])=1$ for every measurable $B$.

Comment: Oops~ the definition that I meant is what #bof said in the answer. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose your definition of a "null set" is a set $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that, given any $\varepsilon\gt0,$ we can find a sequence $\{I_n\}$ of open intervals such that $A\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|I_n|\lt\varepsilon$ where $|I_n|$ is the length of $I_n.$

Assume for a contradiction that $[0,1]$ is a null set. Then there is a sequence $\{I_n\}$ of open intervals such that $[0,1]\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|I_n|\lt1.$ Since $[0,1]$ is compact, there is some finite $k$ such that $[0,1]\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^k I_n.$

Let $f_n$ be the characteristic function of $I_n,
$ i.e., $f_n(x)=1$ if $x\in I_n,$ and $f_n(x)=0$ if $x\notin I_n.$ Then $\sum_{n=1}^{k}f_n(x)\ge1$ for all $x\in[0,1],$ so
$$1=\int_0^11dx\le\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^kf_n(x)dx=\sum_{n=1}^k\int_0^1f_n(x)dx\le\sum_{n=1}^k|I_n|\lt1,$$
which is absurd.

Comment: It is a important key that we can find a 'finite' number K because [0, 1] is compact, right?

Answer (score 1):

Given a subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can say that $X$ isn't a null set if $int(X) \neq \emptyset$ (it's not a definition). So, since $int([0,1]) = (0,1) \neq \emptyset$, we have that $[0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$ isn't a null set.

Comment: I'm sorry but can't understand Anyway thanks for answering my question.